# Is AppleScript encrypted/hidden/secure after it is exported to application as "Run Only"?

Tags: applescript

Is the script hidden from the user of the application after it is exported as run only?

Tried searching this over internet, but couldn't find the exact answer. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit after answers:**
Once the script is exported to an application and the script is deleted. Is there a way for the app user to see/manipulate the script from the application content files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not hidden, but it cannot be opened and edited in an AppleScript editor.

Comment: I meant once the script is exported to an application and the script is deleted. Is there a way for the app user to see the script?

Comment: Applications cannot be opened with AppleScript editor, the editor is meant only for script files.

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about the **script** : *...  the script from the application content files*

Comment: Please read my question again, I have updated it with more details.

Comment: I read the edited question. Once again: The script in the resources folder of the exported application *is not hidden, but it cannot be opened and edited in an AppleScript editor*.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It cannot be opened. IMO, it is hidden too.

Comment: No, it is not hidden, it is located in ./Contents/Resources/Scripts

Comment: No way, no hacks. Definitely.

Comment: Perfect. That helps. Thanks 